# Нажата ли клавиша? Tkinter-Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, key

Везде искал так толком и нечего и не нашел:(
Подскажите пожалуйста как работать с событием `Key` (`KeyPress`) у `bind` в `Canvas`-е???
Мне нужно определить нажата ли клавиша **Q**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493213/how-can-i-bind-a-key-event-to-a-python-tkinter-canvas-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Главным экземпляром класса в `Tkinter` обычно является `root`, по сути являясь нашим окном. А вот `Canvas` - холст, навешивается уже на `root` и `Canvas`-ов у нас может быть несколько поэтому и обработчик нажатия клавишь правильнее накидывать на сам `root`.

```
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()


def click_button(event):
    print("press q")


root.bind("<q>", click_button)
root.bind("<Q>", click_button)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Да это делается почти также, только не `root.bind`, а `canvas.bind`.

Comment: Да, но если вы попробуете это сделать, окажется, что программа таки не отрабатывает нажатия клавиш. В комментариях к вопросу дали ответ в виде ссылки на англоязычный SO где говорится о том что дополнительно нужно ещё перевести фокус на наш Canvas. Поскольку ответ был дан не мной, я не могу дополнить свой.